# Two empty arrays appear unequal

Tags: node.js, coffeescript, underscore.js

I'm working with some tests and trying to assert that a property gets set on object initialization:

```
var Varity = exports.Varity = function Varity () {
  this.options = extend({}, standardOptions, Varity._globalOptions);
  this.expectations = [];
};
```

and then in my test:

```
When -> @varity = new @subject.Varity()
Then -> expect(@varity.expectations).to.deep.equal([])
```

FWIW, I am using mocha with mocha-given and (hopefully obviously) coffee-script. The assertion library is actually `indeed` (which is something I wrote). I am fairly certain that `indeed` is working as 1) the following is true:

```
expect([]).to.deep.equal([])
```

and 2), logging @varity.expectations, both at the end of the constructor, and in the test, shows that it IS an empty array.

I've also placed logs inside `indeed`'s implementation to assure that it's getting to the correct code paths, and I've logged the actual and expectation there. They both log as `[]`. Inside `indeed`, I'm using _.isEqual to do deep object comparisons. Logging the following returns false:

```
_(actual).isEqual(expectation); // where actual is "@varity.expectations" and expectation is "[]"
```

So I traced the code into `_`'s implementation and began logging. And found that the hangup is here (inside the `eq` method - I just searched for isEqual and it was the first hit, if anyone wants to look at the code themselves):

```
var aCtor = a.constructor, bCtor = b.constructor;
if (aCtor !== bCtor && !(_.isFunction(aCtor) && (aCtor instanceof aCtor) &&
                         _.isFunction(bCtor) && (bCtor instanceof bCtor))) {
  return false;
}
```

Logging aCtor and bCtor gives this:

```
[Function: Array]
```

So they appear to be equal, but the log I put inside the `if` runs, so `aCtor !== bCtor` is evaluating to true!

Just for thoroughness, the following DO also report as true:

```
expect(@varity.expectations.join('').split('')).to.deep.equal([])
expect(@varity.expectations.toString()).to.deep.equal([].toString())
expect(JSON.stringify(@varity.expectations)).to.deep.equal(JSON.stringify([]))
expect([].slice.call(@varity.expectations)).to.deep.equal([])
```

But this is false:

```
expect(@varity.expectations.constructor).to.deep.equal([].constructor)
```

And this is true:

```
expect(@varity.expectations.constructor.toString()).to.deep.equal([].constructor.toString())
```

Is this a case of hidden (non-enumerable) properties throwing off the comparisons? I'm not setting anything else on `this.expectations` (actually the code printed there - the Varity constructor - is the entirety of the constructor).

EDIT:
I have a guess that the problem is coffeescript related. Two identical functions are not `===`:

```
function () {} === function () {} // false
```

They're only equal if they are actually THE SAME function. In theory, the two Array constructors should be the same function. The fact that they're not makes me suspect the problem is with coffeescript. One of the arrays comes from coffeescript and one from javascript. I can't imagine that coffeescript is not using the default array constructor, but maybe there's some kind of magic happening at compile time? For point of reference, I am using coffeescript version 1.6.1 (and only for testing).

Comment: I removed the mocha tag because it is most definitely not a problem with mocha. MAYBE it's coffeescript (still unlikely I think), but it's not mocha.

Answer (score 0):

First, I was right that this was not a problem with my `indeed` library. I've recently observed the same behavior with `should.js`.

Second, this IS a coffeescript compilation thing. Classes compile to expressions (rather than declarations) meaning that:

```
class Foo
```

compiles to

```
var Foo;
Foo = (function() {
  function Foo() {}
  return Foo;
})();
```

rather than

```
Foo = function Foo () {}
```

Thus, the constructor of Foo is `[Function: Function]` (the closure) and not `[Function: Foo]`. It seems something like this happens for arrays, causing an empty array (or object) generated in javascript to be different than one generated in coffeescript.

Third, I've written an underscore fix for this that I use in my tests:

```
_.mixin({
    fix: function(thing) {
        return JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(thing));
    }
});
```

which can be called like this:

```
Then -> expect(_.fix(@varity.expectations)).to.deep.equal([])
```